# Facebook Graph API: find all public pages I like in a single request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authorization

I would like to know which objects returned from `/me/likes` are public ie. don't require authorization.

So far, I haven't found a better solution than making another request to `/?ids=<IDs>` without the access token, where `<IDs>` is a comma-separated list of IDs obtained from the previous request.

Is there any field indicating whether an object is public? Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "public"? Pages are per se requestable by their unique object_id. So I don't understand your question...

Comment: I mean visible to unauthorized users. Some FB pages aren't public due to age and/or country restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of what you're asking for when you get the auth toke. If you have all boxes unchecked you will get just public information from the request. You'll know this by the pop-up asking for authorization saying

> "Graph API Explorer will receive the following info: your public profile."

How ever if you have the box checked that says "user_likes" you'll get a list of all the likes. The authorization will say.

> "Graph API Explorer will receive the following info: your public profile **and likes**."

If you just want to return the id of the things you like you can use this.

```
me?fields=likes{id}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to get the liked pages. The problem is: how to recognize which of them are public (visible to unauthorized users)?

Comment: So I did some playing around with graph and a page that I manage.    There's no way for a page to be set to be view-able/like-able by specific people. The page's posts can be "targeted" to specific people based on things like age, gender, location.   Pages are either "Published" or "Not Published". Not published pages are only view-able by the admins of that page.   From the user side to see what pages a user likes can be set with privacy settings to either "Me Only", "Friends", "Public", or "Custom". This setting can be set for differnet types of pages like "Sports Teams", "People", "Other"..

Comment: So to figure out what is publicly view-able on user you could get the user's like with out the auth token, then then them with an auth token to see "user_likes". Then have your program compare the two sets for data for similarities.

Comment: It's impossible to get user's likes without an access token, but I do not mean to. I'm interested in public visibility of liked pages (not the list of my likes) and doing all this with only one HTTP request (with token).

Comment: All published pages on Facebook are publicly visible. Only non-published pages are not public, only the page admin(s) can see them. Only "Groups" have the ability to be private or secret.

Comment: If a page is not publushed there's a "is_published" field with a Boolean value

Comment: Unfortunately, certain pages aren't public due to age and/or country restrictions. But I can't find any field or edge that indicates such cases in the list of my likes.